# Wildcard characters and unaccent in pg-promise query

Tags: postgresql, wildcard, sql-like, pg-promise, unaccent

I use pg-promise@8.4.4 and I would like to have wildcard characters and the `unaccent` function of the PostgreSQL.

My `pl/pgsql` query has something like

`WHERE  unaccent(p.name) ILIKE (''%'' || unaccent($1) || ''%'')'`

I want to make it into a pg-promise query like

`uniqueQuery('select id, name from place WHERE unaccent(name) ILIKE  \'% unaccent($1) #%\' ', [name])`

Without the `unaccent` it works fine. When I add the `unaccent` , I get a synta error : `error: syntax error at or near "ονομα μερους"` (`ονομα μερους` is an the string I am searching for).

How can I combine the wildcards with the `unaccent` ?

Thanks

Comment: If you can work out an example that works within pgAdmin, then it will be possible to advise how to change it for `pg-promise` query formatting. Without such an example it is not clear whether the issue is with your SQL or the query formatting.

Comment: If I understand what you ask, this works : `uniqueQuery('select id, name from place WHERE name ILIKE  \'%$1)#%\' ', [name])`. If I search for something with tones I get nothing and I should, this is why I need the `unaccent` (`όνομα μέρους` is the same as  `ονομα μερους` , but the first has tones and gives back nothing) . Also, a SQL simpler query that works with `unaccent` is this `SELECT p.id, p.name, p.geom  FROM place p WHERE  unaccent(p.name) ILIKE unaccent('%κοιλαδα%') ;` . Thanks

Comment: Then you should use `ILIKE unaccent(\'%$1#%\')`, which is the same as `ILIKE unaccent(\'%$1:value%\')`. See the [Open Values](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#open-values) syntax.

Comment: Thanks. My angular just flopped,I will debug angular and test your suggestion and let you know.

Comment: @vitaly-t Hi again. This is not working. If I do `unaccent(name)`, the results have the name data with an `unaccent` name, not a `name` name. In simpler terms, look : the result is `{ id: '3', unaccent: 'κοιλαδα' }` but it should be `{ id: '3', name: 'κοιλαδα' }`

Comment: Also all the results are unaccent. In simple SQL the results are accent, they have tones etc. but with this approach they end up unaccent.

Comment: Use `as.format(query, values)` to get the resulting string without executing it, and then see what is wrong with the SQL, then we can figure out how to fix the formatting for it. Otherwise, it is all blind guessing.

Comment: Thanks. Working on it.

Comment: This is the string, that `as.format` gives back : `select id, unaccent(name) from place WHERE name ILIKE  unaccent('%κ%')` . I might be wrong, but this looks normal to me. All the problems remain. Unaccent removes all tones and if I search with tones I still cannot find anything, because I guess unaccent removed them ? Sorry, I am out of ideas, but I am willing to help you . So, anything you need, tell me.

Comment: You should diagnose the result SQL in pgAdmin, and then fix the formatting as required.

Comment: Ah, the query should be generalQuery('select id, name from place WHERE unaccent(name) ILIKE  unaccent(\'%$1#%\') ', [name]). The `unaccent` must go in the WHERE,  not the SELECT part. Now it works fine. I am so sorry for wasting your time vitaly. You are a good and helpful developer. Feel free to turn your comments to an answer, so I can upvote and choose as accepted. Thanks I'm gonna go and hit a brick wall with my head now.